# Cannot access updated state or props inside onPanResponderMove

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gesture, use-state, panresponder

What am I Trying to do:  To change the state in response to user's up/down swipe.
Environment: React native 0.61.5

I have the component as follows.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { View, PanResponder } from 'react-native';

function SimpleWrapper(props) {
  const { children } = props;

  const [abc, setabc] = useState(0);

  console.log('SimpleWrapper', abc);

  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => handleShouldSetPanResponder(evt, gestureState),
      // onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => handleShouldSetPanResponder(evt, gestureState),
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => handleShouldSetPanResponder(evt, gestureState),
      // onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => handleShouldSetPanResponder(evt, gestureState),
      // onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => console.log('onPanResponderGrant', gestureState),
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => handleonPanResponderMove(evt, gestureState),
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => {}
      // onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => handlePanResponderRelease(evt, gestureState)
    })
  ).current;

  const handleShouldSetPanResponder = (evt, gestureState) => {
    const { dy } = gestureState;
    const isvalid = evt.nativeEvent.touches.length === 1 && Math.abs(dy) > gestureConfig.gestureIsClickThreshold;
    return isvalid;
  };

  const handleonPanResponderMove = (evt, gestureState) => {
    const { dy, vy } = gestureState;
    console.log('in handleonPanResponderMove:', abc, gestureState);
    if (dy < 0) {
      setabc(abc + 1);
    } else if (dy > 0) {
      setabc(abc - 1);
    }
    // }
  };

  return (
    <View {...panResponder.panHandlers} style={}>
      {children}
    </View>
  );
}

export default SimpleWrapper;
```

Basically i want to increment/decrement the state parameter inside onMoveShouldSetPanResponder,

Now,
On First fire of onMoveShouldSetPanResponder, 'abc' is incremented/decremented successfully. The topmost console in the component also shows new value.

However,
After that in **all** consecutive fires, the console inside the onMoveShouldSetPanResponder function always prints abc as **0** (i.e. the initial value). It never changes.

Is it that we cannot access updated state inside onMoveShouldSetPanResponder? Am i missing something or is there another way to do this?

Comment: did you try putting the log inside the if or else if ?

Comment: @aravind_reddy Yes, tried that, same thing. only initial value is printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The abc variable is a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) you can pass a callback to a state setter: `setabc(currentValue=>currentValue + 1);`